# how can i find start and end date using spacy?

Tags: date, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to use spacy (or any other program you know of) to extract the start and end date from the text of a contract. I am currently able to color and label all the DATES using `displacy.render(doc, style="ent")`. But again, I need to distinguish between start and end date. Any idea how I can do that? Maybe apply more training to a model? How can I do that? Thanks for your help! yishairasowsky@gmail.com

My Environment
Operating System: windows 8.1
Python Version Used: 3.7.2
spaCy Version Used: 2.2.2
Environment Information: I prefer to use jupyter notebooks, so that i can see what i am doing. but py files i guess are ok too.